# Magento 1.9.0.1 : Custom Checkout

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1

I am trying to implement something new, I guess. I want to use magento as shopping cart for my new site where I WANT TO SEND few custom fields that will be filled during checkout process TO EXTERNAL application, that may or may not reside on same server, ONLY IF PAYMENT IS SUCCESSFUL. These custom fields upon succesfull transaction need to be sent through post method. I hope I am clear on this. Please guide me on this, how I can achieve this.

Comment: I got order details on success page after posting this and I am now looking at using same values and post them.

Answer (score 1):

So what I did for something similar was create a custom module and create an observer to catch the get

> $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

that is fired when the order is submitted. Maybe you can tie into that and fire your own POST after the getOrder() is sent. Not sure if this is what you are looking to do but its an idea.

Comment: your idea is good. tx